# Mach exception in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, crash, mach

I sometimes get following exception:

```
[Mach] exception: 0x%x, count: %d, code: 0x%llx 0x%llx
[Mach] Skipping registered port - it is invalid
[Mach] Skipping registered port - mask does not match
signal %d, info %p, uapVoid %p
```

I do not have any idea what these exceptions are about. Can somebody throw any light on this?

Comment: are you getting this error message on simulator or iphone device?

Comment: I am getting this on iPhone 5S. However, I do not get any such exception if I run it on iPhone 5.

Comment: can you tell us , on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I don't do any special things, it happens suddenly.

Comment: Read this: https://www.plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.2-beta1/mach_exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

try enabling the interception of generic exceptions:

in the left side of xcode, select "breakpoint navigator", on the bottom of left side click on "+", select "add exception breakpoint", a new item named "all exception" added in the breakpoint list. after click again on "+", select "add symbolic breakpoint", and write [NSException raise] inside text area named "symbol".

Now try again run your project.